# unlimited size String buffer in c

Tags: c, string, char, buffer

I'm creating a 'string'

```
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]
```

but when this gets full, I want to concatenate it onto a pre-existing string, but it needs to have unlimited length and repeat this process until I've read all the data.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've described is an alternate definition for `realloc`.

Answer (score 8):

I have used **open_memstream** to achieve this in the past.

This function opens a stream for writing to a buffer. The buffer is allocated dynamically and grown as necessary, using malloc. After you’ve closed the stream, this buffer is your responsibility to clean up using free or realloc.

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Streams.html

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void)
{
  char *bp;
  size_t size;
  FILE *stream;

  stream = open_memstream (&bp, &size);
  fprintf (stream, "hello");
  fflush (stream);
  printf ("buf = `%s', size = %zu\n", bp, size);
  fprintf (stream, ", world");
  fclose (stream);
  printf ("buf = `%s', size = %zu\n", bp, size);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this one more time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to dynamically allocate memory, using [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/) and [`realloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/).

Answer (score 2):

you can try to use `realloc`

```
char *temp = NULL;
char *buffer = (char*) realloc (temp, BUFFER_SIZE*sizeof(char));
```

you will get dynamic amount of memory based on `BUFFER_SIZE`